# Is $f(x) = \frac{\cos(x)}{x}$ Lebesgue integrable over $E = [0,1]$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

My instructor stated that it is straightforward to show that $f(x) = \frac{\cos(x)}{x}$ 
 is not Lebesgue integrable over $E = [0,1]$.

I know that I'll have to show that $$\int_E \biggl|\frac{\cos(x)}{x} \biggr| = \infty$$ just not sure how to.

Comment: Near zero you have $cosx$ is equivalent to $1-x^2$

Answer (score 1):

$\cos(1) \le \cos(x)$ on $[0,1]$, so

$$\int_{(0,1)} \frac{\cos(1)}{x}\,dx \le \int_{(0,1)}\frac{\cos(x)}{x}\,dx.$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Note that this logic doesn't work for $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ over the same interval because the lower bound for $\sin(x)$ over that interval is actually $0$. Then using an approximation like Gustave's is very useful.

Comment: I see what you are saying. thank you